# How to stop Android Studio from using the "m" prefix?

Tags: android, android-studio

Title says it all - how to stop this crazy convention to appear in every code generated by Android Studio? 
I've looked at the Code Generation tab in the Code Style settings, but the textfields for prefixes and suffixes are all empty already.

Comment: "in every code generated by Android Studio" -- if you are referring to activities and such, those are driven by templates, and AFAIK you have no means of changing those templates' behavior.

Comment: As crazy as it seems, why not simply use it? You'll find it everywhere since it's Android's system sourcecode style http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions and it has spread from there.

Comment: I have my reasons why I don't want to use it, which are out of scope of this question. I want to use my Java conventions I use on other Java projects.
@CommonsWare Is there really no way to manually edit the templates? They must be located somewhere on the drive.

Comment: "Is there really no way to manually edit the templates? They must be located somewhere on the drive." -- your edits will then be clobbered by the next update to Android Studio. There are some undocumented ways to set up your own templates, though I have no idea if they still work. See [this repo for an example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-rba). Personally, I just don't use the templates, as the `m` prefix is the *least* of their problems.

Answer (score -1):

File > settings > Editor > code style > java
Go to code generation tab and remove the m prefix.

Although I suggest to use the standards :) .

Comment: If you read my whole question, you can see that I've looked in there and there is nothing to remove...